# Creating a table with vertical seperators,fixed colums length and headers in android

Tags: android, file, android-layout, tableview

I am trying to create a Table in an Android layout.
I want this table to be a normal table, like a gridView or datagridView, the same table you can get using Microsoft Word:

I want to define the columns length (so the text beneath will be straight) and a separators between columns and lines, and of course a nice column header.

So far I tried to use TableLayout, but It is not the same:

1. The text is not aligned  - depending on the text length,  the columns are not one beneath the other because each line is just a string.
2. no separator between columns.

The seperation between lines I made my self adding this to the TableLayout after each line:

```
View v = new View(this);
 v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
 v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
```

What I want to achieve is that the user will be able to view a file I am writing for him. This file is Tab separated (between columns) and by opening it up with Excel on a computer it is shown as a table.

If there is another way (instead of this table I am trying to create) to view this Tab separated file I will be glad to know how.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the FixedGridLayout.java [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/FixedGridLayout.html) in ApiDemos example that comes with the Android SDK. To see how you can implement it see com.example.android.apis.animation.LayoutAnimations.java [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/LayoutAnimations.html)